# Manage Sub-variables in Bash

Tags: bash, loops, variables, variable-assignment

I want to manage subvariables in Bash. I can assign the subvariables, but I dont know how to use it:

```
#/bin/bash

n=1

for lvl in 1 2;
do
    export key$n="${RANDOM:0:2}"
    let n=$n+1
done


for num in 1 2; do

echo $key$num

done
```

If I use `echo $key$num`, it print number sequence of variable `$num`, and not the random numbers

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays

Answer (score 5):

Use arrays.

```
for n in 1 2; do 
  key[n]="${RANDOM:0:2}"
done

for num in 1 2; do
  echo "${key[num]}"
done
```

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays.

Also, in bash you'll generally do better counting from 0 instead of 1, and you don't need to `export` variables unless you want to run some other program that is going to look for them in its inherited environment.

Answer (score 1):

You may use arrays (see @MarkReed), or use `declare`:

```
for n in 1 2; do
    declare -- key$n="${RANDOM:0:2}"
done

for n in 1 2; do
    v=$(declare -p key$n) ; v="${v#*=}" ; echo "${v//\"/}"
done
```

The same using functions:

```
key_set () # n val
{
    declare -g -- key$1=$2
}

key_get () # n
{
    local v=$(declare -p key$1) ; v="${v#*=}" ; echo "${v//\"/}"
}

for n in 1 2; do
    key_set $n "${RANDOM:0:2}"
done

for n in 1 2; do
    key_get $n
done
```

Comment: You can also use `printf`: `printf -v key$n '%s' "${RANDOM:0:2}"`. And to retrieve it you can use indirect expansion: `v=key$n; v=${!v}` (and that's the part that OP was missing).

Comment: I really dislike your `key_get` function: don't use `declare -p` for that: you're using a subshell, then you need to parse the string `v` to remove (wrongly) the quotes (it's okay here, but your method is not general: it'll fail if there are quotes in field). Whereas using indirect expansion would solve all these more elegantly, efficiently and robustly.

Comment: In fact; I just wanted to get a trial with declare... indirect expansion is better, and arrays even more.